# redisの永続化設定をOFFにしたい

Tags: redis

Redis 3.2.10を使っています。

パフォーマンスの問題で永続化をしないでメモリだけで処理させたいのですが、設定ファイルのドキュメントにあるように

> save ""

を書き、元々設定されている

> #save 900 1
>   #save 300 10
>   #save 60 10000

をコメントアウトしています。
この状態で再起動したり、redis-cli config getで状態を確認しても、

> redis-cli config get save
>   1) "save"
>   2) ""

と反映されているのですが、dirとdbfilenameに設定されている場所にファイルが書き出されてしまいます。
どうすれば、RDBファイルを書き出さない設定にできるのでしょうか？

dirの設定を書き込み権限の無いディレクトリにすることで保存はされなくなりますが、ログファイルにエラーが並ぶのであまり良くない状態だと思っています。
RDBファイルの書き込みに失敗するとCPU負荷が上がるという情報も見かけたのですが、こちらの環境では確認できませんでした。

**以下回答のコメントを元に追記**
書き出されているファイルは、dump.rdbでdbfilenameに設定されているものと同じです。
またdirの設定を書き込み権限のある/var/lib/redis/に設定すると、この場所に永続化ファイルが書き出されます。
AOFの設定は

> appendonly no
>   appendfilename "appendonly.aof"

となっていて、appendonly.aofは作られていません。

dirをコメントアウトや/など、書き込み権限のない場所に設定すると、5分毎に
Failed opening the RDB file dump.rdb (in server root dir /) for saving: Permission denied
のエラーがログに出ます。

repl-diskless-syncはyesでもnoでも違いはありませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

設定ファイルで`appendonly`の値を確認してください。もし、`yes`になっていると追記専用ファイルが書き出されます。追記専用ファイルは、SAVEとは別の設定になっています。

Comment: appendonlyはnoでした。またappendfilenameが別の名前になっているので書き出されているのはRDBファイルのようです。

Comment: 全くわからないので本家の方を調べると、コメントに永続化をしない設定にしてもfailover processでできるかもしれないというのがあります。関係ありますか？
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785383/

Comment: ありがとうございます。プロセス自体はずっと生き続けていて落ちている様子がなく（psコマンドの起動時間はそのまま）レプリケーションまわりの設定もnoなので、謎なままです。RDB保存失敗のエラーログが書き出されるタイミングを見ていると5分に一回処理が動こうとしている（60秒に1万回の書き込みはありませんが、300秒に10回は書き込まれているシステムです）ので、save ""の設定がどうも効いていないようにも思えます。わたしの方でも引き続き調べてみます。